# Shorthand to return first non-empty function result in PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have two functions, `getData1()` and `getData2()`, which both return an array which may or may not be empty.

Now I want to make a third function that first tries `getData1()`. If the return value is not empty, the new function should return the value from `getData1()`, otherwise it should try `getData2()`, and if that too is empty it returns an empty array.

I tried

```
return getData1() || getData2() || [];
```

but I don't get the return value of `getData1()` or `getData2()`, instead I get `true` or `false`.

Obviously I could do

```
$x = getData1();
if( empty($x) ) $x = getData2();
return $x;
```

or

```
return !empty(getData1()) ? getData1() : getData2();
```

But I'm curious if there is a way to construct something more elegant like the first statement (the one that doesn't work)?

Comment: Honestly i think the 3rd statement you put down is the most elegant of the 3. Although I suggest doing it more like `return empty(getData1()) ? getData2() : getData1();`

Comment: @AdamBrinded, that will potentially cause `getData1()` to be called twice.

Comment: @Nigel Ren thats true, but not if the two original functions (`getData1()` and `getData2()`) are passed as arguments to the third function.
Ie
`function third($foo, $bar)
{
  return empty($foo) ? $bar : $foo;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, you can use a double ternary expression:

```
return getData1() ?: (getData2() ?: []);
```

An empty array evaluates to `false` so you don't need `empty().`You can also skip the second argument of the ternary expression as that will then be the result of the first: In this case the array - which is what you want - but you cannot use that with `empty()` as it will give you a boolean.

And if the functions always return arrays - empty or not - you only need:

```
return getData1() ?: getData2();
```

Now if `getData2()` is also empty, it will return that result, an empty array.

Comment: I was just going to put your second option as an answer when I saw the edit come up.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, that is the nicest solution if the functions always return arrays.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! I had a feeling there was something like this, just never seen the empty ternary operator before.